# Convert userInput (string) to UserInput(int) mid for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, string, integer

I am working on a program that has to do with arrays. I decided that the input the user provides to be a string to later being converted to an integer once it is determined it is one. This way the program wouldn't run into an error when words/letters are entered. The issue I am having is the conversion from string to int. I want to change that because later in the program I am going to search the array for a given value and display it and its placement in the array. This is the code I have thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


//check if number or string
bool check_number(string str) {
   for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
   if (isdigit(str[i]) == false)
      return false;
      return true;
}
int main()
{
    const int size = 9 ;
    int x, UserInput[size], findMe;
    string userInput[size];
    cout << "Enter "<< size <<" numbers: ";

for (int x =0; x < size; x++)
    {
        cin >> userInput[x];
            if (check_number(userInput[x]))
                {//the string is an int
                }
             else
                {//the string is not an int
                    cout<<userInput[x]<< " is a string." << "Please enter a number: ";
                cin >> userInput[x];}
    }
int i;
for (int i =0; i < size; i++)
    {
          int UserInput[x] = std::stoi(userInput[x]); // error occurs here
    }
for (int x= 0; x< size; x++)
    {
        if (UserInput = findMe)
        {
         cout <<"The number "<< UserInput[x] << "was found at " << x << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            //want code to continue if the number the user is looking for isn't what is found
        }
        
    }
return 0;
}
```

Made comments here and there to kinda layout what I want the code to do and whatnot. I apperciate any help you can give, thank you.

Comment: `if (UserInput = findMe)` _always_ evaluates to `true`. Check for equality using `if (UserInput == findMe)`

Comment: The formatting of the returns in `check_number` is giving me anxiety

Comment: Also `UserInput` is an array. Why are you comparing that to an `int`?

Comment: This whole program could be written in less than 15 lines of _"real"_ c++ code. Looks like you're overcomplicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: Why is the indentation such a mess?  You are just making life hard for yourself.  See: http://format.krzaq.cc/

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
int UserInput[x] = std::stoi(userInput[x]);
```

declares an `int` array of size `x`, to which you are assigning a single `int` (the result of `std::stoi`), which obviously doesn't work.

You need to assign an `int` to a particular index of the existing array, like this:

```
UserInput[x] = std::stoi(userInput[x]);
```

---

Given this comparison `if (UserInput = findMe)`, which should actually be `if (UserInput == findMe)`, it seems you want to declare a single `int` which stores the result of `std::stoi`. In that case, you should use a different name than the array, and write something like this:

```
int SingleUserInput = std::stoi(userInput[x]);
```

---

Also, please indent your code consistently, and compile with all your warnings turned on. Your code will be easier to read, and the compiler will point out additional problems with your code. And please don't use `using namespace std;`, it's a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why do u even need to use another loop to convert the string value to int. stdio.h header file does provides with preinstalled functions to make your work easier...

```
for (int x =0; x < size; x++)
    {  
        getline(cin,userInput1[x]);
       UserInput[x]=stoi(userInput1[x]);
    }
```

stoi() function converts the string input to int, and you can call it dynamically as soon as you  enter your string input,It will make you work easier and reduce the time complexity